# How to Avoid Using Getters/Setters in C++?

Tags: c++

I understand the reason why we should avoid using getters/setters, but I don't know how to avoid using them.

For example, I have three classes as follows,

1. `A` (`private: point_B`)
2. `B` (`private: point_C`)
3. `C` (`private: val_C`)

A has a private member `point_B` which is a pointer that points to `B`, and `B` also has a private member `point_C` which is a pointer that points to `C`. And `C` has a private `int` value `val_C`.

How can I access `val_C` in `A`?

### Update:

In this case,

1. `A` is a class called `state`, which has the address `point_B`.
2. `B` is a class called `node`, which has a pointer call `pointer_C`.
3. `C` is a class called `base_file`, which has two derived classes called `file` and `directory`.

### Update 2:

Ty guys for you help. Some of you are really trying to help instead of acting like someone who knows everything. I appreciate it. 
Sry I can't post the whole assignment here since its too large even without documents. I'll post professor's answer here if you guys are interested tomorrow.

### Update 3:

Please find reference [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html)
The right thing to do is to leave the implementation to specify class.

### Update 4:

The answer is to not to access private value in each class, but to implement functions to use them. That explains why making them private at the first place.

Comment: A better question: if the user can easily access `B` from `A` and `C` from `B`... why are they *private*? And if there's supposed to be some invariant being maintained by `A`, why is the user able to directly access and modify `B` through `A`?

Comment: Because our great professor write 3 classes instead of one.

Comment: Why do we want to avoid getters/setters?

Comment: Because of encapsulation

Comment: Maybe the idea is to have methods that are actions and thus don't need accessing the internal properties. What do these classes represent?

Comment: @RedX, please see the update

Comment: If they are all private, you don't have a lot of choice but to create getter functions and setters too, if you want to change the value. I'm guessing you can't add friend declarations to `B` and `C`?

Comment: Guys.... we are forgetting `friend` classes here..

Comment: It might be easier if you posted the actual class definitions and a code snippet that illustrates the access you need [imagine if the members weren't private]. Otherwise, you'll need setters/getters or what about `friend` if you can't add them? The actual code may decide the best [least harmful] way to go.

Comment: @PaulRooney True, B and C are friend in this case. But making two classes already breaks the encapsulation..totally confused.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks a lot. But I'm not sure if I can make them all friends since in this way there's no need to separate them into classes.

Comment: @MsYvette ..ty but what I am confused is not about this.

Comment: What are the problem contraints? That is, prof has given you 3 class defs [with private stuff]. What are you allowed to change? Can you move private to protected? Can you add public set/get funcs for private data? Is the 3 way split a requirement, or just what you did? Please ... Post the stuff. If you do, we [all] can probably help. It's in your best interests to do so. Setters/getters are to be avoided [general guideline], but, sometimes, they can be the only way [and from what you've said so far, they may be necessary--or just friend everything]

Comment: @CraigEstey ty. Maybe its all about how to implement instead of a general idea of using getter/setter.

Comment: I believe so--how to implement. get/set in general is easy: `int MyX::get(void) { return my_private; }` and `void MyX::set(int val) { my_private = val + 1; }`. Tools in the toolbox. Real problem is which tool for the job. I'll look forward to your solution post tomorrow.

Comment: "Why do we want to avoid getters/setters?  Why private data attributes?"  One reason has to do with the engineering ideas called cohesion and coupling.  Getters, setters and friends create the _least_ desirable cohesion and worst coupling.  It is simple to avoid them.

Comment: Based on update #4, it seems that set/get was the answer. Perhaps not straight setval, getval, but something more useful/higher level (e.g. if private field was `persons_date_of_birth`, maybe `current_age()` which also does some calculation)

Answer (score 10):

Maybe a little clarification is in order -- getters and setters aren't meant to be avoided at all costs; they have their place.  The reason people say they should be avoided is because one goal of good object-oriented program design is *encapsulation* -- that is to say, each class should keep the details of its own implementation as private as possible, so that users of that class don't need to know (or care) about how the class was implemented.  This becomes increasingly important as the program gets larger and more complicated, because a human programmer can only keep so many details in his/her head at once, and if the programmer has to remember everything about how class C works while simultaneously writing/debugging class A, that's an additional/unecessary cognitive burden that at some point will cause the programmer's brain to explode.

So, getting back to the main question -- how to avoid getters and setters -- the way to do it is to define your classes' interfaces at a higher level of abstraction than as simple repositories for state variables.  (After all, if you wanted a simple collection of state variables, there's no reason to use a C++ class at all, you could simply declare a C-style struct instead)

For example, if your class C was intended to represent, say, a slot machine, a poor interface to class C might include lots of getters and setters, like this:

```
int getNumCoins() const {return numCoins;}
void setNumCoins(int newCoinCount) {numCounts = newCoinCount;}
void setDisplayedResult(const string & displayStr) {result = displayStr;}
int getDisplayedResult() const {return result;}
```

... and the poor programmer who was forced to use class C would have to write code like this:

```
playersWallet--;  // take a coin out of the player's wallet
c.setNumCoins(c.getNumCoins()+1);  // insert the coin into the machine
string newResult = "10 J A";   // somehow figure out what the machine should display
c.setDisplayedResult(newResult);  // and make the machine display it
if (c.getDisplayedResult() == "7 7 7")
{
   cout << "YOU ARE WINNER!" << endl;
   int numCoinsWon = 5000;  // jackpot!
   c.setNumCoins(c.getNumCoins()-numCoinsWon);  // deduct from machine's balance
   playersWallet += numCoinsWon;  // add to player's balance
}
[... and so on...]
```

Note that in the above code, the programmer had to think about all of the internal mechanisms of the slot machine, and write his own code to handle each step of its operation.  With good encapsulation, on the other hand, the slot machine's public interface would be much simpler and more opaque, like this:

```
// returns the number of coins the player won on this round
int pullTheBigLever();
```

... and the programmer who was using this API might write code like this:

```
playersWallet += (c.pullTheBigLever() - 1);  // -1 for the coin the player put in
```

Note that there is only one line of code, and that the programmer didn't have to think at all about how the internals of the slot machine worked.  This avoids exploding-programmer-brain-syndrome, and just as importantly it means you (or someone else) can go back later and change the private implementation of how the slot machine works without breaking the code that interacts with the slot machine.

So when are getters and setters acceptable?  Answer:  when there really isn't any higher level of abstraction to be had.  If you are writing a class that represents a light switch, then just being able to examine the switch's current position, or specify a new position for it, may be all the functionality you need.  But in many (most?) cases you are implementing the functionality of something more complex than that, and the more of that complexity you can hide behind your public interface, the happier users of that class (including you) will be.

Answer (score 2):

Short answers, in OOP, classes should have "properties" as part of their public API. Properties can have have things like getters, setters and change notifications, as appropriate. Wether a  getter directly returns a private member variable, that is an implementation detail,  and could change as needed. Distinguish the concept of property from the concept of member variable.

When thinking about it like this, the direct answer to your question is, that there's nothing you should try to "avoid", other than having unnecessary readable properties.

Note that often there is no explicit syntax or support for properties in an object oriented language (popular counter-example: [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)), so it's easy to think they are same thing as a member variable with a setter and a getter. But the overlap is sort of a coincident, and not something you should care about when using a class. In a way, there is no getter for a member variable, there is only a getter for the property, even if it happens to map 1:1 with a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

> How avoid using getters/setters in C++.

To avoid setter/getter, all code that accesses a data attribute of class C, must be part of a class C method.

Alternate wording: bring the code that uses the data attribute inside the class.

---

update 2016/01/25

Would an example help?  I find it trivial to avoid getters and setters (and public data and friends, etc.)  I suppose I'm just used to it.

I recently completed yet another implementation of the game-of-life.  The whole game is the entertainment value of watching the cells change patterns.  Impressively complex behaviour from a small set of rules.

My class Cell_t has ONLY private data, No getters, no setters, and no friends.  No other class has access to any cells data.

Here is a snippet of that part of my game illustrating how easy it is to live without getters, setters and friends creating the undesirable coupling and cohesion:

```
// somewhere in GameOfLife exists 
std::vector<Cell_t> m_ptCellVec;  // a vector of cell ptrs


GameOfLife::exec(...)
{
   // ... preliminary stuff

   do {

      // ... some preliminary stuff

      // NOTE 1
      for ( auto it : m_ptCellVec ) it->countNeighbor();

      // NOTE 2
      for ( auto it : m_ptCellVec ) { it->updateDisplay();}

      // .... more stuff

      if(timeElapsed > timeLimit)  break;
      if(m_generation > genLimit)  break;
   }while(1);
}
```

NOTE 1 -- The class GameOfLife does not count neigbors ... each cell does its own counting.  The next state is computed from these counts.

NOTE 2 -- The class GameOfLife does not update the display ... each cell updates it's own little piece of the screen.

THUS, there is no getter of Cell_t state, or next state, or living-neighbour count, or dead-neighbour count, etc.

With respect to this aspect of these two classes

```
The cohesion (of Cell_t) is functional, the most desirable.

The coupling (of GameOfLife_t to Cell_t) is 'none', also the most 
desirable.

Changing the name or type of a Cell_t private data attribute has no 
impact on any other code.
```

---

Oh, and a debug routine I often add (for another example):

```
std::string Cell_t dump() {
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << // .... anything you want to 'dump' from this instance 
   return (ss.str());
}
```

I use the method name dump() to indicate an intent for a 'deeper' investigation of the activity of a specific Cell_t ... I have sometimes generated tabular data of state changes, with time stamps.

I often have a very similar method called show(), which typically provides a string for the user ...

These two examples, perhaps, illustrate the idea that a getter is simply bypassing an important aspect of the design process - naming what you are doing.

Comment: Agreed. But the problem is we can only use members in class A.

Comment: True if you know how to access C without writing getters in each classes.

Comment: You didn't understand... did you?... I and @Douglas (may be) are saying there is no point of getters and setters, if the members of `class` are private. Since the are `private`, only the class should be allowed to `access` or `modify` them, that is, all the logic/code belonging to them should be inside `class C`. that's why the word `private`,

Comment: @Minato ty all the way but you didn't understand the question

Comment: "Why do we want to avoid getters/setters? Why private data attributes." One reason has to do with the engineering ideas called cohesion and coupling. Getters, setters and friends create the least desirable cohesion and worst coupling. And it is trivial to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question stated in Problem could be modified. The question should not be "How can I avoid getters and setters?". This question is also related to other questions like "Should this method be a non-static member, static member, friend or helper?" or "Should this property be private or protected?". A better question to ask yourself is rather, "Who needs to access a particular property".

One way of writing classes which are easy to maintain is to limit the number of functions which have access to a specific property. This does not necessarily mean that no function should ever have access to a private property or that getters/setters should never be used. Take for example the class `std::vector`. Which can be simplified to something like this (with a lot of reservartions). The actual implementation of `vector` is normally much more sophisticated and may have different internal implementation but this simplified construction will be used to show a point.

```
template<class T, class Allocator<T> a = basic_allocator<T>>
class vector {
    size_t sz;
    size_t cap;
    Allocator a;
    T* elem;
    // ... private methods
public:
    // public methods and operators.

}
```

This class lets the developer access all elements in the internal array, where data is stored. This is done either via the operator `[]` (unchecked) or via the function `at` (checked). The developer have full rights to read or write to these elements. Without this access the `vector` class would be fairly useless and people would revert to use arrays instead. The class also provides getters to `sz` and `cap` via methods `size()` and `capacity()`. However `sz` and `cap` is otherwise seen as internal information and the developer is not allowed to change these directly. Instead the developer can use methods like `push_back()`, `pop_back()`, `shrink_to_fit()`, `resize()`, ... To add or remove data, manage allocated memory, etc ... The reason is that these operations requires some quite advanced memory handling and modifying these variables would cause leaks and/or crashes. Further, the developer does really not need to bother about these abstractions, since the developer only need the elements in the array.

So to conclude encapsulation is good and need to be considered. However this does not mean that the developer is never allowed to directly modify properties of some classes.

Comment: Anyway, since most of answer is for the origin question, leave if unmodified is good for who's searching "how to avoid getters/setters".